# Should I use a fontawesome cdn or include the css file in my react project?

Tags: build, webpack, font-awesome, cdn

I was going to add fontawesome to a project I am working with (using Microsoft's MVC spa services and VS2017) but a coworker told me to include it in the build. Is this supposed to be better? if so, how do I do that? Just copy the css file somewhere and webpack will take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

I would be using the CDN version as it is always upto date and the load in minimal. No point using server space really is there?